# find general solution to $\dot{x}=Ax$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Given $A_{n\times n}$ real matrix and $0\neq v,w\in\mathbb{R}^n$ such that for every $t\in\mathbb{R}$ $x(t)=ve^{-t}+wte^{-t}$ is a solution to $\dot{x}=Ax$
> For $n=2$ find the general solution.
> find a Non-trivial solution to $\dot{x}=A^2x$

I'm not sure what am I suppose to find,because the given $x(t)$ is a general solution or do I need to find general form of $A$?

Edit:
I've tried taking the given equation $x(t)=ve^{-t}+wte^{-t}$ and multiply from the left by $A$ and then $\dot{x}=Ax(t)=Ave^{-t}-wte^{-t}$ and maybe from this equation I can get another solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the form of $x(t)$, it is implied that $A$ has a repeated eigenvalue of $-1$. (Can you see why?) Can you proceed now?

Comment: I can see that $-1$ has at least multiplicity of 2 but not sure how to proceed..:(

Comment: So $A^2$ must have an eigenvalue $1$ with multiplicity at least $2$

Comment: Ok,but how can I find general solution for $n=2$?

Comment: For n=2 the given solution is already the most general solution.  The constants v, w are determined by initial conditions.